# How to aggregate prices in OHLC-data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with columns:

```
ID, START_DTTM, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE
```

I have to aggregate data hourly.

So, I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(START_DTTM) START_DTTM,
    MAX(HIGH) AS HIGH,
    MIN(LOW) AS LOW
FROM 
    MY_TABLE
GROUP BY 
    ID, DATEPART(DAY, START_DTTM), DATEPART(HOUR, START_DTTM)
```

and it works, but I can't pull OPEN and CLOSE.

I tried something like this:

```
FIRST_VALUE(OPEN_PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY 
DATEPART(DAY, START_DTTM), DATEPART(HOUR, START_DTTM) ORDER BY START_DTTM)
```

And, of course, it doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery for that:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(START_DTTM) START_DTTM, MAX(HIGH) AS HIGH, MIN(LOW) AS LOW,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_asc = 1 THEN OPEN_PRICE END) as open_price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_desc = 1 THEN CLOSE_PRICE END) as close_price
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DATEPART(DAY, START_DTTM), DATEPART(HOUR, START_DTTM) ORDER BY STRT_DTTM) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DATEPART(DAY, START_DTTM), DATEPART(HOUR, START_DTTM) ORDER BY STRT_DTTM) as seqnum_desc
      FROM MY_TABLE
     ) t
GROUP BY ID, DATEPART(DAY, START_DTTM), DATEPART(HOUR, START_DTTM);
```