# SQL aggregate by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue finding some price value in an SQL query. I put a comment where the error is. It shouldn't average, but find first and last date values for open and close.

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, aa.date) / 5 * 5, 0) AS [Date],     
    AVG(aa.[open]) AS [Open], /** this is wrong it should be open from minimal date of the group*/
    MAX(aa.hight) AS [High],
    MIN(aa.low) AS Low,
    AVG(aa.[close]) AS [Close],   /** this is wrong it should be close from maximal date of the group date */
    SUM(aa.[volume]) AS [Volume]
FROM
    (select top (10000) * from [dbo].[kraken_btc] ) AS aa 
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, aa.[date]) / 5 * 5, 0) 
ORDER BY
    Date
```

I deleted all the useless added stuff and post response for other as it should have been given, [this other question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398288/how-to-aggregate-prices-in-ohlc-data)
[How to aggregate prices in OHLC-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398288/how-to-aggregate-prices-in-ohlc-data)

Comment: sample data and expected results will help here. We can't run your SQL, nor see what you do or want to, so we can't see what's "wrong".

Comment: it relatively well know  probleme for a personne dealing with financial  data but i added some detail no need downvote its specialized ;) will add c# and hope for a nice devellopper ;)

Comment: Please, do not post sample data as images, instead post it as _formatted text_.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. If it's a reletively "well known" problem, however, then wouldn't you expect there already to be an answer on Stack Overflow? Anyway, sample data should not be an image; it's almost useless to other users then. Sample data should be provided as what it is `text`, or (even better), as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements so that the volunteers here can make use ofit.

Comment: @Sami sry not used to post much sql question tough itsimple for someone its the job.aniway tryed post as CSV.

Comment: @lamu only similar i seen on Stack Overflow look ugly subquery that will burn my money management

Comment: At first glance your SQL is suspect: "FROM    (select top (10000) * from [dbo].[kraken_btc] ) AS aa 
  GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, aa.[date]) / 5 * 5, 0)"
why are you doing this redundant select? you are grouping but not performing any grouping operations

Comment: why suspect?????

Comment: Please do not place a solution to the problem inside the question. Answers should be written using the form below. Also, if the linked question already provides an answer to your own, we can instead mark this question as a duplicate, so that future visitors may easily find it.

Comment: its bit modified the is working with Datemioffset from SQL

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was:

```
-- SET 
DECLARE @Period int ;
SET @Period = 5 ; 
select  
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,[Date]) / @Period * @Period, 0) AS AGG_DATE,
min([Date]) Min_Date,
max([Date]) Max_Date,
max(high) as Highest,
min(low) as Lowest,
min(case when rn_asc = 1 then [open] end) as [Open],
min(case when rn_desc = 1 then [close] end) as [Close]
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,[Date]) / @Period * @Period, 0)
        order by [Date]) as rn_asc,
        row_number() over (partition by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,[Date]) / @Period * @Period, 0)
        order by [Date] desc) as rn_desc,               *
        from   OHLC
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
       DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,[Date]) / @Period * @Period, 0)
```